# Свойства цифровой подписи Windows файлов с помощью Java

Tags: java, windows, winapi, dll, signature

Возможно ли в `Java` с помощью какого либо `API` (желательно API, а не путем парсинга файла) узнать свойства цифровой подписи Windows файлов (`exe, dll`, тд)?

А именно:

```
Signer, Issuer, Digest algorithm, Timestamp, Timestamp signer
```

А также описание файла:

```
Product name, Product Version
```

Если это возможно, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как?

Comment: Начните с `JNA`. Библиотека для упрощения вызова нативных функций. Если ничего не получится, переходите на более сложную основу`JNI`. Тем или другим способом вызывайте функции Windows API. В крайнем случае можно сделать внешнюю утилиту на C, и запускать её из Java, результат получить через конвейер.